# Some questions about Bogoliubov transformation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-optics

consider a Hamiltonian, after mean-field approximation, can be written as
$$\hat{H}=\sum_{p}(\epsilon_{p}+gn_{0})a_{p}^{\dagger}a_{p}+\frac{1}{2}gn_{0}(a_{k+p}a_{k-p}+\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{k+p}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{k-p})$$
where $g$ is the coupling strength between particles and $n_{0}$ is the particle density.

Denote $\hat{H}=UMU^{\dagger}$ and $U=\{a_{k-p},a^{\dagger}_{k+p}\}$. Suppose the new basis is written as

$$\alpha_{p}=u_{p}a_{k-p}+v_{p}a^{\dagger}_{k+p}$$ and $$\beta_{p}=v_{k}a_{k-p}+u_{k}a^{\dagger}_{k+p}$$

Then the Bogoliubov spectrum would be the spectrum of $\sigma_{z}M$, where $\sigma_{z}=\{1,0;0,-1\}$

We can write $\hat{H}$ as:

$\hat{H}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{p} [(\epsilon_{k+p}+gn_{0})a_{k+p}^{\dagger}a_{k+p}+(\epsilon_{k-p}+gn_{0})a_{k-p}^{\dagger}a_{k-p}]+\frac{1}{2}gn_{0}(a_{k+p}a_{k-p}+\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{k+p}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{k-p})$,

in this case,

$M=\{\frac{1}{2}(\epsilon_{k+p}+gn_{0}),\frac{1}{2}gn_{0};\frac{1}{2}gn_{0},\frac{1}{2}(\epsilon_{k-p}+gn_{0})\}\tag{1}$

However if we write $\hat{H}$ as

$\hat{H}=\sum_{p} (\epsilon_{k+p}+gn_{0})a_{k+p}^{\dagger}a_{k+p}+\frac{1}{2}gn_{0}(a_{k+p}a_{k-p}+\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{k+p}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{k-p})$

$M$ would be:

$M=\{\epsilon_{k+p}+gn_{0},\frac{1}{2}gn_{0};\frac{1}{2}gn_{0},0\}\tag{2}$

After calculation, one can see (1) and (2) give different spectrum.

And in (1), the energy corresponding to $\beta_{p}$ is equal to that of $\alpha_{-p}$. But this relation does not hold in (2).

Generally, I see most textbooks tackle this problem like (1). However, I did not see where is wrong in (2). Is there symmetry forbidding writing $\hat{H}$ as (2)?